# CASE WHEN condition 1 AND condition 2 then x else y postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to put two conditions inside a case when statement but I am getting a syntax error in postgresql

```
case when
condition 1 and condition 2 then X else Y 
condition 3 and condition 4 then Z else Y

end
```

What is the correct syntax to have the columns take x in the case of both conditions and y otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
case
    when condition 1 and condition 2 then X
    when condition 3 and condition 4 then Z 
    else Y
end
```